# How can I tokenize a text efficiently?

Tags: tokenize, text-processing

Given a text **(T)** and a dictionary **(D)**, how can I find all words that occur in the text?

**A1.** One can assume that there are just few repetitions of characters in **T**, for example, the **T** is in Chinese.

**A2.** Iterating over the **D**, as one may suspect, is costly. Thus it either should be preproccessed, broken down or simply: Multiple iterations should be avoided.

**A3.** The upper length of a word is **L** and comparatively small compared to the text.

**B1.** The simplest solutions might be to just iterate over **D** for every substring of sensible length I have in my **T**. 
This method would definitely guarantee me that all words are found. This however seems vastly inefficient.

**B2.** Another idea would be to iterate over the text once, retrieve all characters in **T** in a set and proceed as in **B1** for finding all words.

**B3.** This variation could work like **B2**, however would use/assert that **D** is in lexicographical order. That means, it would actually only check words with the same starting characters.
Possibly I could also use a look ahead of the characters following my current character **T**. I would iterate over the **D** just once, over **T** multiple times. This however seems bearable.

**B4.** Here, I would also proceed like in **B3**, however re-order **D** in such a way, that more likely occurring words **T** are checked earlier. The problem here: How do I find out, what words are occurring more likely? I would have to first digest a lot more data beforehand and be then sure that what I then measure, is actually what I want to measure..

Surely, there are many other possibilities, likely more sophisticated ones. But what is the current state of the art? How can one do this / approach this problem best?

Comment: Hashmaps. However, this question does not seem appropriate for SO as it is asking for an opinion from many possible solutions

Comment: Not really, I am not interested in anyone's favourite algorithm, however in how this is doable. If you consider any algorithm opinion based, then there wouldn't be much legit questions/answers left here.

Comment: Process the dictionary and convert to a data structure where strings can be looked up efficiently, such as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a hash table. Note that in actual Chinese text words are not separated by spaces, which makes the problem much more interesting; there is no way to parse a Chinese text into words without an understanding of Chinese -- is 十三五 (shi san wu) one word, two words or three words?